# Why does rand() compile without including cstdlib or using namespace std?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++

According to the book I'm reading, `rand()` requires `#include <cstdlib>` in C++
However, I am able to compile the following code that uses `rand()` without `#include <cstdlib>`  nor `using namespace std;` in Visual Studio 2015.
Why are these two not needed to compile? Should I include cstdlib?

C++ Code:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::cout << rand() << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: You can compile with the `/showIncludes` option (in the iDE's project properties under "C/C++ | Advanced | Show Includes") to see exactly how `stdlib` is being included.

Comment: @MichaelBurr I see now, the output in Visual Studio shows that iostream was including cstdlib. Is there a way to know which files are being included directly and which indirectly? I'm just curious

Comment: The level of indentation of the output using the `/showIncludes` option indicates which header included which other header. For example, with VS 2015 Update 1, `<iostream>` only directly includes `<istream>` - all other headers pulled in are indirectly included by `istream` or headers deeper in the hierarchy.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are two issues at play:

1. Standard library header files may include other standard library header files. So `iostream` may include `cstdlib` directly or indirectly.
2. Header files with C-standard library equivalents (e.g. `cstdlib`) are allowed to bring C standard library names into the global namespace, that is, outside of the `std` namespace (e.g. `rand`.) This is formally allowed since C++11, and was largely tolerated before.

Comment: What do you mean by "directly or indirectly"?

Comment: @JorgeLuque I mean e.g. `iostream` may include `utility` which may include `limits` which may include `cstdint` which may include `cstdlib`.

Answer (score 4):

`iostream` may include `cstdlib` directly or indirectly. This brings `std::rand()` and `::rand()` in the scope. You are using the latter one.

But yes, you should not count on this and always include `cstdlib` if you want to use `rand`. And in `C++` code don't use `rand`, there are better ways to generate random numbers.

Comment: Is `::rand()` the same as `rand()`? Is that considered to be in the global namespace?

Comment: Yes `::rand()` is same as `rand` in your case.

Answer (score 2):

You definitely should use the relevant include file for what you are using in your code. It saves you from surprises when you update the compiler/libraries to the new version. I think adding `std::` in front of `rand` is a much better idea than to use `using namespace std;` - but either way, it's a good idea to NOT rely on it existing without a namespace, although that tends to be the way it works in most places to allow backwards compatibility for C-code.