# Error C2679: "binary '<<': no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'std::string' (or there is no acceptable conversion)"

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio

my little brother is currently learning how to code in C++, and as a way to test different ways Arrays can be use, he started a program that would have the computer generate a random number, then output a particular emotion (stored in an array) based on that number.  For some reason however, the section of code where the output goes doesn't want to work the way I suggested.

The way I thought it should be written was 'cout << "I'm" << emotion[x] << endl;', which I'm sure has worked for me in the past, but for some reason the computer won't accept that.  I haven't actually coded in C++ for a while, so maybe something has changed or I forgot how 'cout' works.

It's probably something super simple and stupid that I should have caught already, but I just can't see it.  Here's the rest of the code, in case the problem is somewhere further up the line.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;


string emotion[6];

int main() {
        emotion[0] = "Happy";
        emotion[1] = "Sad";
        emotion[2] = "Angry";
        emotion[3] = "Fearful";
        emotion[4] = "Disgusted";
        emotion[5] = "Suprised";

        srand(time(NULL));

        int x;
        x = (rand() % 6);

        cout << "I'm " << emotion[x] << endl;

        system("PAUSE");
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "computer won't accept it"? Compiler error? Runtime error? Unexpected behavior?

Comment: add cstdlib in your program. it will work.
and can you tell what exactly output you want?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Exactly as you thought, a simple mistake indeed. You need to `#include <string>` for it to work as you expect and [**Here Is Why**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16506095/do-i-have-to-use-include-string-beside-iostream).

You might also need to `#include <cstdlib>` for `srand` and `rand` and [Here is why you may not need it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35910043/why-does-rand-compile-without-including-cstdlib-or-using-namespace-std).

Comment: _facepalm_  I had completely forgotten about #include <string>.  Thank you.

Comment: Glad we were able to help :) Please accept/upvote my answer if it answered your question.