# How to generate random numbers between 2 values, inclusive?

Tags: c++, random, user-input

I need help figuring out how to generate a set amount of random numbers between two user-inputted values, inclusively. Just so you know, I have searched for this but am not finding what I have just stated. Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int userBeg, userEnd, outPut;

    cout << "Enter a start value: ";
    cin >> userBeg;
    cout << "Enter an end value: ";
    cin >> userEnd;

    srand(time(NULL)); //generates random seed val

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
      //prints number between user input, inclusive
    outPut = rand()%((userEnd - userBeg) + 1); 
    cout << outPut << "  ";
    }//end for

    return 0;
}//end main
```

I'm confused with the output I get for the following ranges: 
1-100 yield output numbers which fall in-between, but not including, the boundaries such as 50, 97, 24, 59, 22.
But, 10-20 yield numbers such as 1, 14, 6, 12, 13. Here, the output is outside of the boundaries as well as in-between them. What am I doing wrong?

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: `outPut +=userBeg`

Comment: If you are using C++11, take a look at [`std::uniform_int_distribution`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/uniform_int_distribution)

Comment: If `rand` is fast but low quality, then you can (probably) get better randomness by dividing its result by some suitable small constant, to remove the (influence of) the last few bits, before taking your bite of bits.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[rand](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/rand) returns number between 0 and `RAND_MAX`. By taking modulo `userEnd - userBeg + 1` the boundaries will be limited to 0 and `userEnd - userBeg`. If the random number should be within given boundaries, then `userBeg` should be added, so the calculus becomes

```
    outPut = rand()%((userEnd - userBeg) + 1) + userBeg;
```

Comment: This answer will produce biased results, some numbers will be more likely than others. Better to use the more modern random number facilities of C++ rather than `rand`.

Comment: The question was regarding boundaries, not `rand` accuracy.

Comment: This method *reduces* the randomness even if `rand` is perfect. It might suffice for non-critical applications, but everybody should be aware of the caveat.

Answer (score 12):

Using the c++11 [`random`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/random/) library.

You could use [`std::default_random_engine`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/random/default_random_engine/) (or any other random engine) with [`std::uniform_int_distribution`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/random/uniform_int_distribution/).

The values you pass to `std::uniform_int_distribution` will be the lower and upper bounds of your random range.

e.g.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <random>

int main()
{
    const int nrolls = 100;

    std::default_random_engine generator;
    std::uniform_int_distribution<int> distribution(0,9);

    int p[nrolls]={};

    for (int i=0; i<nrolls; ++i)
    {
        p[i] = distribution(generator);
    }

    std::cout << "uniform_int_distribution (0,9):" << '\n';
    for (int i=0; i<nrolls; ++i)
    {
        std::cout << i << ": " << p[i] << '\n';
    }
}
```

If you wish to seed the random engine, create it like.

```
unsigned seed = std::chrono::system_clock::now().time_since_epoch().count();

std::default_random_engine generator(seed);
```

Answer (score 4):

It's still experimental, but it is exactly what you want

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/randint

```
#include <iostream>
#include <experimental/random>

int main()
{
    int random_number = std::experimental::randint(100, 999);
    std::cout << "random 3-digit number: " << random_number << '\n';
}
```

Edited: it's really random http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random

Comment: I'd eliminate the `experimental` part of this answer, there's a standard solution available since 2011: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/uniform_int_distribution

Comment: Yes, I've already known it. I just want to give another short approach for the question. Btw, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

For the rand to work you need to do:

```
#include <cstdlib>

int main() {

    int Min = 103;
    int Max = 113;

    int Number = std::rand() % (Max + 1 - Min) + Min;

    return 0;
}
```

I omitted the `cin` for clarity. (Max + 1 - Min) makes it inclusive. + Min sets the minimum value!

So stuffed into a function you may use:

```
int randint(int Min, int Max) {
    return std::rand() % (Max + 1 - Min) + Min;
}
```

After testing it works with negative numbers as well as positive.

#### Sample outputs (with a loop and cout):

**11-23**

```
The number is: 13
The number is: 18
The number is: 14
The number is: 17
The number is: 18
The number is: 18
The number is: 23
The number is: 15
The number is: 11
The number is: 22
The number is: 22
The number is: 11
The number is: 22
The number is: 16
The number is: 14
The number is: 21
The number is: 16
The number is: 19
The number is: 15
The number is: 13
The number is: 17
```

**1239-1242**

```
The number is: 1240
The number is: 1242
The number is: 1239
The number is: 1241
The number is: 1241
The number is: 1241
The number is: 1239
The number is: 1240
The number is: 1240
The number is: 1240
The number is: 1242
The number is: 1240
The number is: 1242
```

Comment: std::rand() is in cstdlib not random http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/rand

Comment: Hmm... Actually compiles and runs just fine without any includes

Comment: Of course, then you shouldn't include library that isn't used.

Comment: I have already updated the answer. Thanks for pointing that out! :D

Comment: std::rand make me some trouble, on ideone.com, if I use C++14 then it just fine, but for G++ 5.1 and G++4.3.2 I must include cstdlib.

Comment: Find it out :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35910043/why-does-rand-compile-without-including-cstdlib-or-using-namespace-std Since you use C++11

Comment: Well that explains. Turns out I had included iostream when testing the code! I have updated the answer to include the cstdlib header to avoid compiler errors if anyone should just copy paste it. Thanks for the link!

Comment: @Carl F. Thanks for your answer! In your output, however, the random numbers generated include the boundaries. How would I go about writing my code if I didn't want to include my boundaries?

Comment: You would simply `std::rand() % (Max - Min - 1) + (Min + 1);` shuffle the plus and minus 1's a little. Keep in mind though that this it is not optimal to have both ends be non-inclusive as a random between the value 1 and 1 will always yield 2 for example.

Comment: Thanks! My prof requires that the output does not include the boundaries. In the case of the same max/min values, I'll add an if statement to check and notify the user they can't equal.