# What is the difference between 'rand' and 'std::rand'?

Tags: c++, namespaces

I'm a (scientific) Python programmer and just started a course on C++.
I find the way to use 'packages' and accessing their functions confusing.

To generate pseudo random numbers in C++ I was advised to use `rand()` function from `cstdlib` ([documentation](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/rand/)). This caused me to write the following code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

int main()
{
    // Create random int that predicts future
    std::srand(time(NULL));
    int answer = std::rand() % 10;

    std::cout << answer;
    return 0;
}
```

I figured out that I did not need to write `std::rand()` simply using `rand` would work as well, see below. What is the best practise, using `std` or not? From [indirect cstdlib](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35910089/11075461) I got that this is because I use a C library.
I'm afraid that this will cause clashed between 'packages' if both of them have a `rand()` defined as a function?

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

int main()
{
    // Create random int that predicts future
    srand(time(NULL));
    int answer = rand() % 10;

    std::cout << answer;
    return 0;
}
```

In python these a function could be reached by `package.function()`, is this possible in C++ as well. AKA something like accessing the random number generator by `cstdlib::rand()`.

P.S. The `rand` function is purely an example. I want a way to separate the function based upon the package they come from.

Comment: Some system header files might include other system header files. But it's an unknown implementation detail that you should not rely on. Always explicitly include the header files specified for the functionality you want to use.

Comment: "_I was advised to use `rand()`_" - Drop that and go for `<random>` instead.

Comment: I'm sorry for asking a duplicate question. Thanks for pointing that out NathanOlivier.

Comment: I hope that, after the edits, the question is not duplicate anymore.

Comment: The only purpose of a namespace is to avoid name clashes. Having rand and std::rand in the same scope together is perfectly fine. No need to worry about that. We don't really have packages in C++ 17. It's just namespaces. The include is basically a copy paste.

Comment: Worth your time: [rand() Considered Harmful](https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/GoingNative/2013/rand-Considered-Harmful).

Comment: Thanks for the responses, I've moved on to <random>. I now also understand why `rand()` exists both outside and inside the namespace std.